# Symfony2: Pass a second object to a Voter

Tags: symfony-2.8, symfony-security

I'm using a voter to determine whether or not the logged in user can edit a given object. One of the criteria requires a comparison with another object but I'm not sure how to pass this into the voter. I cannot use the constructor arguments as it is not a predefined value.

Basically I would like to do something like this:

```
 protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token, $comparedObject)
            { if ($subject->getProperty1 == $comparedObject) 
    {return true;} 
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late but maybe this answer is going to be helpfull for someone.

One thing that you can do is pass an array of values instance of a single $subject object.

For example, from Twig you use your function as:

```
{% set data =  { 'subject': yourRealSubject, 'compared_object': comparedObject } %}
{% if is_granted('can_edit', data) %}        
...
...
{% endif %}
```

(You can do the same from PHP code).

So then in your Voter:

```
class MyVoter  extends Voter{


        // ...

        protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $data, TokenInterface $token) {

                $subject = isset($data['subject']) ? $data['subject'] : null;
                $comparedObject = isset($data['compared_object']) ? $data['compared_object'] : null;

                if(!$subject || !$subject instanceof \Namespace\To\Subject){
                      throw new Exception('Missing or invalid subject!!!'');
                }

                // do whatever you want ...

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create additional property of "subject"  where you can put "compared object".

```
// Inside action.
public function myBestAction(Request $request) 
{
   // My super code... e.g. we have received from ORM a $post. 

   // Create property on the fly to put $comparedObject. 
   // Perhaps creating property dynamically is not good practice, therefore you can create permanent with getter and setter. 
   $post->comparedObject = $comparedObject;
   $this->isGranted('can_edit', $post);
} 

// Now inside voter.
private function canEdit($subject)
{
   $comparedObject = $subject->comparedObject;

   // Compare $subject(post) with $comparedObject and return true or false...
}
```